# How to calculate the sum of an attribute in a list Jpa?

Tags: spring, spring-boot, kotlin, spring-data-jpa, spring-data

If I wanted to have an attribute of my order table so that it adds up to the total price of the list of products, which I should use since I could not find a solution, please

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "ordenes")
class Orden(
        @Id
        @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
        val id: Int? = 0,

        val createdAt: LocalDateTime? = LocalDateTime.now(),
        val updatedAt: LocalDateTime? = LocalDateTime.now(),

        val nombre: String? = "",
        val direccion: String? = "",
        val telefono: String? = "",


        @OneToMany(cascade = [CascadeType.MERGE])
        @JoinColumn(name = "parent_id")
        val products: List<Product>? = mutableListOf()
)
```

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "products")
class Product(
        @Id
        @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
        val id: Long? = null,
        val name: String? = null,
        val description: String? = null,
        val price: BigDecimal? = null,
        val img_url: String? = null,
        val createdAt: LocalDateTime? = LocalDateTime.now(),
        val updatedAt: LocalDateTime? = LocalDateTime.now()

        )
```

Comment: I don't understand the problem: products.stream.mapToInt(p -> p.getPrice()).sum(); Written in java but point stands.

Comment: I would like to have the total sum of the entire list of products of the order entity, as an attribute of total_order, but I wouldn't know how to do it in jpa

Comment: the sum of the price of each product, as a total

Comment: It is a bad design idea, such things should be calculated via a function call, each time when it is needed. But if you insist, create a field `val: totalPrice` and everytime a product is added or removed this field has to recalculate its value with the code I have written before (jpa won't do it for you). It is a dangerous solution though because easily situations can arise when the information is outdated either on jpa side or in the database. To put simply don't do it, use a function.

Comment: It is that I did not want to calculate the total price by the frontend, what solution would you propose, thank you very much for your answer

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just add a function inside of Orden:

```
BigDecimal function calculateTotal() {
    BigDecimal total = 0;
    for (Product product : products) {
        total.add(product.getPrice());
    }
    return total;
}
```

(written in Java, but I kept it simple so you can easily adjust it into Kotlin)
and call this function on every Orden object when you need it.